# Enviar y recibir datos por puerto Serie

Tags: c#, serialport

estoy teniendo problemas al intentar comunicarme con un dispositivo por puerto Serie. Probe con un software la comunicación sin problemas, pero a la hora de implementarlo por consola en c# no estoy recibiendo respuesta. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar  o sugerir como puedo enviar comandos y obtener una respuesta

```
 SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM7",38400,Parity.Even,8,StopBits.One);

       port.Open();
       bool isopen = port.IsOpen; //me muestraque esta conectado

       byte[] iniciarScr = {0xf2,0x00,0x03,0x43, 0x30, 0x40,0x88,0x8c }
       port.Write(iniciarScr, 0, iniciarScr.Length);
       byte[] bufferRespuesta = new byte[256];
       var bytesRead = port.Read(bufferRespuesta, 0 bufferRespuesta.Length);
```

En bytesRead se queda pegada la consola esperando una respuesta

Comment: Debes de leer el manual del dispositivo al que te quieres conectar. Los comandos varian con cada proveedor y dispositivo y dependiendo de que es lo quieras por ejemplo enviarle comando o bien que el dispotivo de los mande automaticamente. Ya hiciste eso?

Answer (score 0):

No puedo escribir comentarios, pero verificaste la línea:

```
var bytesRead = port.Read(bufferRespuesta, 0 bufferRespuesta.Length);
```

Le falta una coma luego del cero.

Por otro lado, porque no intentas con otro método:

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string DataIn = String.Empty;
    DataIn = port.ReadExisting();
}
```